# RConnect app deployment fail with nloptr package and R4.3.1

Tags: r, redhat, shinyapps, community-server-connector

We recently updated our Red Hat 8 servers and R updated at the same time from 4.2.3 to 4.3.1.  When we go to deploy apps now, I get an error with the nloptr package that I can't seem to resolve.  I've updated the package in sudo R but still get the same error.  Would anyone be able to point me in the rite direction please?

'/usr/lib64/R/bin/R' --vanilla CMD INSTALL --preclean '/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/tmp/RtmpoUyRr2/packrat-install-e34a66e8d5615/nloptr' --library='/opt/rstudio-connect/mnt/app/packrat/lib/x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu/4.3.1' --install-tests --no-docs --no-multiarch --no-demo